# Regex to match last character in string - C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I remove the last ';' in a string?

In case of comment at the end of the string I need to return the ';' before the comment.

**Example**:

```
"line 1 //comment
line2;
extra text; //comment may also contain ;."
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so please let us see the Regex

Comment: can't you just .Split(';') and then work with the array os strings?

Comment: Could you please update your question with expected output

Comment: @PaulF this is a non-trivial question. The regex would have to recognize and *discard* the comments

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim String.Split isn't "just", it generates new temporary strings for each operation that need to be garbage collected. A regex can be several orders of magnitude faster simply because it *doesn't* generate temporary strings.

Comment: This might also be an xy problem.  What are you actually wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok

Comment: What can the lines contain? Strings like `"this is; a string"`? I suggest writing a parser unless the format is very basic.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly ugly with Regex, but here it is:

```
var str = @"line 1 //comment

line2; test;

extra text; //comment may also contain ;.";

var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"^(?:(?<!//).)+(;)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matches[matches.Count - 1].Groups[1].Index);
}
```

We get a match for the last semicolon in each line (that isn't preceded by a comment), then we look at the last of these matches.

We have to do this on a line-by-line basis, as comments apply for the whole line.

If you want to process each line individually (your question doesn't say this, but it implies it), then loop over `matches` instead of just looking at the last one.

If you want to replace each semicolon with another character, then you can do something like this:

```
const string replacement = "#";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"^((?:(?<!//).)+);", "$1" + replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

If you want to remove it entirely, then simply:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"^((?:(?<!//).)+);", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

If you just want to remove the final semicolon in the entire string, then you can just use `string.Remove`:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"^(?:(?<!//).)+(;)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    str = str.Remove(matches[matches.Count - 1].Groups[1].Index, 1);
}
```

Comment: How Can I remove this char?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't wrote what you wanna do with the character, so I give you a solution here that replaces the character:

```
string pattern = "(?<!//.*);(?=[^;]*(//|$))";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("line 1 //comment", pattern, "#"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("line2;", pattern, "#"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("extra; text; //comment may also contain ;.", pattern, "#"));
```

Output:

```
line 1 //comment
line2#
extra; text# //comment may also contain ;.
```

Comment: Note that if you have two semicolons in a line this replaces them both, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @canton7 many thanks for your hint, you're completely right! I updated the answer with an extended RegEx that only replaces the last semicolon.